# Get total number of rows in dataframe while reading by chunks

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here I'm trying to read a CSV file in chunks of 100 and creating entries of 10-10.

```
entries = []
for batch in read_csv(StringIO(S3.read(bucket, key)), chunksize=100):
    json = batch.to_json(orient = "records")
    entries.append(json)

    if len(entries) == 10 or <if-it-is-last-chunk>:
        SQS.push(entries)
        entries.clear()
```

How would I know whether this is the last iteration of the loop and push the messages? Or is there any way to find out the total number of records in the CSV (without reading it again)?

Comment: Why not move the <if-it-is-last-chunk> part after the loop? When you end the loop entries contains the last chunk of json and you could push on SQS there. You might want to use a control boolean variable not to push twice.

Comment: Currently it is working this way only. :) But I am still seeking for a proper solution.